# installanywhere launched from ProcessBuilder is not able to take log4.configuration system property

Tags: java, logging, log4j, installanywhere

I am experiencing a strange behaviour. I am launching an installanywhere exe from my java class using ProcessBuilder. I am passing some args for the jvm like

> lax.nl.java.option.additional=-Dvis.oldZoom=false -DSystemRoot="C:\Windows" -Dlog4j.configuration=file:"/location to log4.xml/" -DLOG4J_CONFIG_FILE=file:"/location to log4.xml/" -Dlog4j.debug=true

The last three params are for log4j and they are my problem

I have log4j jars in classpath

> lax.class.path=other jars;log4j-1.2.17.jar

But nothing comes up, there is no log and no java process. What could be missing here?

**Update**
Instead of this

> The last three params are for log4j and they are my problem

Actually what I was trying to say is that they should be there I know that. And I expect the log4j logging to be up and nicely setup after these params and jars inclusion but the problem is that it(logs) don't come up.

Answer (score 1):

lax.nl.java.option.additional in your lax file should define these.

Can you "write" to the lax file if these need to be added or removed ad-hoc during your execution?

Alternatively I would just create a launch config for each set of args you might need, so you have the convenience of just accessing the specific launcher, not having to mess with additional switches.

Comment: See my update I feel I am doing what you are saying but it's not working